# Norm for bounded variations function

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, bounded-variation

Let $f$ be a function defined on an interval $[a,b]$ with bounded variations.
The application $|.|: f \mapsto |f|=v(f) + |f(a+)|$, where $v(f)$ is the total variation of $f$, is a norm.

Why do we need to add the term $|f(a+)|$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$v(f)=0$ does in general not imply that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ !